# Return the first n records per group Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

### My problem

I want to return the top n rows per group ordered by a date in Oracle 10g

### My table

```
EMPLOYEE|START_DATE|DEPARTMENT
Amy     |01-02-1901|Sales
Edwina  |01-02-1902|Mergers
Tawnee  |01-02-1904|Legal
Trudy   |01-02-1998|Sales
Tanner  |01-02-1967|Sales
Kelly   |01-02-1954|Mergers
Jenny   |01-02-1991|Sales
Jacinta |01-02-1924|Legal
Suzanne |01-02-1976|Legal
Jacqui  |01-02-1989|Legal
Jill    |01-02-1989|Mergers
Kate    |01-02-1998|Mergers
Jane    |01-02-1900|Sales
Louise  |01-02-1912|Mergers
Kim     |01-02-1976|Sales
Cara    |01-02-1955|Sales
Kirsten |01-02-1933|Legal
Sarah   |01-02-1998|Legal
```

### Desired outcome

```
EMPLOYEE|START_DATE|DEPARTMENT
Jane    |01-02-1900|Sales
Amy     |01-02-1901|Sales
Tawnee  |01-02-1904|Legal
Jacinta |01-02-1924|Legal
Sarah   |01-02-1998|Legal
Edwina  |01-02-1902|Mergers
Louise  |01-02-1912|Mergers
```

### What I've tried

```
(select * from 
employees where 
DEPARTMENT = 'Sales' and
rownum <3;)
UNION
(select * from 
employees where 
DEPARTMENT = 'Legal' and
rownum <3;)
UNION
(select * from 
employees where 
DEPARTMENT = 'Mergers' and
rownum <3;)
```

*REALLY ugly query*

I'm thinking if there was a way you could you an

```
OVER (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT)
```

but from what I read, this needs to be preceded by an analytic function (count, sum whatever). Is there a more elegant, inexpensive solution?

Comment: You are on the right track. Take a look at the thread Nir Levy pointed to in the comment above. See if you can adapt the solution to your case  - that is the right approach. There are slight variations if there may be ties in your data - if there aren't any, you should be good to go. If the solution there doesn't work, please write again explaining exactly where you found difficulties or what is different in your case compared to that older case. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this non-Windows function approach using a count correlated aggregate query. The idea is to run a department rank subquery and then use that in a derived table that filters outer query by this department rank. Please note your desired results do not return by ordered `START_DATE` but simply query's row number.

```
SELECT main.EMPLOYEE, t.START_DATE, t.DEPARTMENT
FROM 
   (SELECT t.EMPLOYEE, t.START_DATE, t.DEPARTMENT, 
          (SELECT Count(*) FROM Employees sub 
           WHERE sub.START_DATE <= t.START_DATE 
           AND sub.Department = t.Department) AS DeptRank
FROM Employees t) main
WHERE main.DeptRank <= 3
ORDER BY main.DEPARTMENT, main.START_DATE;

-- EMPLOYEE START_DATE  DEPARTMENT
-- Tawnee   1/2/1904    Legal
-- Jacinta  1/2/1924    Legal
-- Kirsten  1/2/1933    Legal
-- Edwina   1/2/1902    Mergers
-- Louise   1/2/1912    Mergers
-- Kelly    1/2/1954    Mergers
-- Jane     1/2/1900    Sales
-- Amy      1/2/1901    Sales
-- Cara     1/2/1955    Sales
```

For the Windows function counterpart:

```
SELECT main.EMPLOYEE, t.START_DATE, t.DEPARTMENT
FROM 
   (SELECT t.EMPLOYEE, t.START_DATE, t.DEPARTMENT, 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Department
           ORDER BY START_DATE) AS DeptRank
FROM Employees t) main
WHERE main.DeptRank <= 3
ORDER BY main.DEPARTMENT, main.START_DATE;
```

---

And as @Matt comments, you may want to handle ties (i.e., employees who started on same day). Both above solutions will output all such employees depending on rank filter. To take one of the ties in correlated subquery, use *Employee* name as tiebreaker (or better yet a unique ID if available):

```
SELECT main.EMPLOYEE, t.START_DATE, t.DEPARTMENT
FROM 
   (SELECT t.EMPLOYEE, t.START_DATE, t.DEPARTMENT, 
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Employees sub 
            WHERE sub.Department =  t.Department 
             AND (sub.START_DATE <= t.START_DATE
                  OR sub.START_DATE = t.START_DATE 
                  AND sub.EMPLOYEE < t.EMPLOYEE) AS DeptRank
FROM Employees t) main
WHERE main.DeptRank <= 3
ORDER BY main.DEPARTMENT, main.START_DATE;
```

And for window-function query use `ROW_NUMBER()` in place of `RANK()`.

Comment: because OP specifically says top n NOT top n WITH TIES it may be good to note that the non-windowed function will include ties and that the window function does as well but that OP could change RANK() to ROW_NUMBER() to eliminate ties.

Comment: Excellent point, Matt. I extended that scenario to your credit!